# threejs apply texture in camera space

Tags: three.js, 3d, texture-mapping

I have a black and white image that I want to use as bumpmap/specular map.

And to make it a bit weird I want to apply it in camera space, instead of object space.
In other words project it from the camera onto an object.

It also means that if I move the object it will "update" as it is moving around the texture.

I couldn't find anything like that in the docs, so I guess the question is: is this possible?